# DROP all tables starting with "EXT_" in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this question may ask many times but I could not find one line SQL statement.
I remember I did it before but now I could not remember how I did

I want to drop all tables whose name starts with "EXT_". Is it possibile to make it happen with one line SQL statement.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use a short anonymous block to do this.

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'EXT_%' )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Include also "cascade constraints" so that the order of dropping those tables will not be an issue if foreign keys are involved.

Comment: if you have tables with small letters don't forget to surround the table name with " characters.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible with only one statement. Usually, I write a sql to get all the tables and then execute the results:

```
select 'drop table ' || table_name || ';'
from   user_tables
where  table_name like 'EXT_%';
```

Comment: To copy all and execute them can be easy with this one.    select 'drop table ' || table_name || ' ; 'from   user_tables where  table_name like 'EXT_%';

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean. Execute this query, copy/paste the results and execute the statements.

Answer (score 4):

This code will DROP not only EXT_% tables, it will act as DROP EXT% also.
Underscore is as special wildcard that acts as '%' but for a single character.

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'EXT_%' )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

In order to achieved desired results you should change your code the way below

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'EXT\_%' ESCAPE '\')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

It *escapes* underscore char in order to be trated literally, **ESCAPE '\'** modifier indicates that escape char is **'\'**

Answer (score 3):

In most of cases  you will find contraints violations. In that case, this script can help you:

```
DECLARE
   c_action CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := 'DROP';
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'STARTINGTEXT_%' )
  LOOP

       FOR reg IN (SELECT uc.table_name,
                      uc.constraint_name
                 FROM user_constraints uc
                WHERE uc.table_name IN (c.table_name)) LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || reg.table_name || ' ' || c_action ||
                        ' CONSTRAINT ' || reg.constraint_name ;
          END LOOP;

  END LOOP;
COMMIT;  
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'STARTINGTEXT_%' )
  LOOP

          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || c.table_name;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name;
  END LOOP;

END;
```